# PHP CURL Bot possible cookie issue?

Tags: php, javascript, session, cookies, curl

I am working on making a web crawler that pulls data from a website and am almost on the home stetch, but I've run into an issue. I can login/retreive the cookie fine, but the website reacts unusual when logged in this way. (Refer to screen shots)

It almost seems as if the cookie becomes useless once the page has been initially loaded (The cookie is still there, I've checked). Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I've tried looking around at similar problems to no avail.

Code:

```
<?
session_write_close();
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, getcwd().'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, getcwd().'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.callofduty.com/"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://profile.callofduty.com/elite/login");
curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://profile.callofduty.com/elite/login"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://profile.callofduty.com/elite/do_login');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'j_username=USERNAME&j_password=PASSWORD');
echo "Initial Dump: <p>";
echo curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://elite.callofduty.com/career/xbox/54d10030cc86b1b9c3162b395d46bffe#/playercardmw3");
curl_exec($ch);
echo "<hr/>Second Dump: <p>";
var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
?>
```

Note: The page works *slightly* better if I am logged in regularly in another background window. There is more information that loads. This confuses me because isn't the cookie dealt with by the PHP script on the server? O_o

--- UPDATE ---
Okay, I'm not sure why because I didn't change anything but now when I load the site it looks normal, just without the information I want ( http://gyazo.com/e326f2f4cdac3e6a4a20fdc9afc62f2d.png?1340088915 ). However, it shows me as logged out. (Note: you cannot view profiles while logged out, it forces you to the login screen)

Here is the printout for the both the echo of the request and the var_dump: http://gyazo.com/ded134560cdf6c6ecf0b27221f35e32b.png?1340110136

As far as I can tell, even though I have gotten the cookie, the site still thinks I'm logged out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: way to steal other peoples IP.

Comment: No IPs were stolen. I just searched "Joe" as a test profile and that's the first thing that came up :P

Comment: i should clarify, IP in this case is intellectual property.

Comment: It's not like I'm going to sell it or anything. I'm just trying to learn how this stuff works. I learn best by modifying already working things.

Comment: Okay, please refer to my update section. It's changed completely now O_o

Comment: @MrCode The first exec echo returns blank, and yes, cookie.txt is being written to fine.

Comment: Look at the first response again but use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);` so that response headers show. Look at the Location header to see if it is trying to redirect you to the account home (to indicate successful login).

Comment: @MrCode The location is "http://elite.callofduty.com"... So it seems like the login was successful. As I said, I shouldn't even be able to see the profile if I wasn't logged in before I got there. What would cause me to lose my session even though the cookie is still there? :S

Comment: Add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);` then after the second request do `var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));` to see the request headers. In the request headers should be the JSESSIONID cookie, check that it matches the one issued by the first request (as seen in the response headers). Add a user-agent string, and if still not working, add an initial request to the login form - humans don't post the login form without actually viewing it first.

Comment: @MrCode Okay, I did what you said and still the same results. The initial request has a JSESSIONID, but the printout from the var_dump doesn't list a JSESSIONID. It does however list a session id. Is that what you wanted me to compare the JSESSIONID with? Because they are not the same, even after the additions. (Updated the source code)

Comment: `getcwd() + "cookie.txt"` (1) This is int(0) (2) Concatenating is done with `.` (3) `getcwd()` needs an ending slash (4) In total: `getcwd().'/cookie.txt'`

Comment: @Wrikken Thanks, I'm still getting used to the PHP syntax XP

Comment: Try setting a referrer maybe?

Comment: Anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

you need to specify the cookie when you jump to other parts of the website do something like this.

```
function login(){
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);//add this line
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);//add this line
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US;  rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, getcwd().'/cookie.txt');
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, getcwd().'/cookie.txt');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.callofduty.com/"); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://profile.callofduty.com/elite/login");
   curl_exec($ch);

   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://profile.callofduty.com/elite/login"); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://profile.callofduty.com/elite/do_login');
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'j_username=USERNAME&j_password=PASSWORD');
   echo "Initial Dump: <p>";
   echo curl_exec($ch);
}

function getPlayer(){
   login();

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_URL,"https://elite.callofduty.com/career/xbox/54d10030cc86b1b9c3162b395d46bffe#/playercardmw3");
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");//add this line
   curl_exec($ch);
   echo "<hr/>Second Dump: <p>";
   var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
}
```

I haven't tested this because you code is a mess, but try it out.